# is it possible to create an onchange event in select tag

Tags: html

but I just want the onchange event to run in only one option

for example :

i have a select tag like this

```
<select name="Interior Details" id="Interior" class="form-control input-lg" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="" disabled >Select Interior Details</option>
    <option value="link kitchen.html" selected>Kitchen Set</option>
    <option value="link bedroom.html">Bedroom Set</option>
    <option value="link living.html">Living Room Set</option>
    <option> Not Choose Anything</option>
</select>
```

i want this option `<option> Not Choose Anything</option>` 
do not move to another html, but the browser keep says the html you're headed does not exist

What should I do

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to complicate things you can just put `value='#'` in your

`<option> Not Choose Anything</option>`

so that it wont redirect to Not Choose Anything page

Another option is to check the value before redirecting.

Change your onchange attr to this. It will call the redirect function in your javascript.

```
onChange="redirect()"
```

Then put this in your javascript .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect () {
    var e = document.getElementById("Interior");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    //'not' is the chosen value in your option Not Choose Anything
    if (!(value === 'not')){
        document.location.href=value;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: but, What should I do if i need to fill the value with a name like 
`<option value="not chose" > Not Choose Anything</option>`

Comment: you will have to check the value first before redirecting. Do you want an answer like that? @ShevaAthalla